# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.os.Handler.post(java.lang.Runnable)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, многопоточность

Только начал работать с Handler . Приложение даже не хочет запускаться , а ошибка вот такая :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.os.Handler.post(java.lang.Runnable)' on a null object reference
                                                                                          at com.example.x.threaddevelopmentpart2.MainActivity$4.run(MainActivity.java:66)
                                                                                          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Вот java код :

```
package com.example.x.threaddevelopmentpart2;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import static java.lang.Thread.sleep;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView text;
    CheckBox checkBox;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    int count;
    Handler handler;

    Runnable updata = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            progressBar.setProgress(count);
        }
    };

    Runnable showInfo = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            text.setText(count + "%");
            handler.postDelayed(showInfo,1000);

        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        progressBar.setMax(count);
        progressBar.setProgress(0);

        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if(b){
                    text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    handler.post(showInfo);
                }
                else{
                    handler.removeCallbacks(showInfo);
                }
            }
        });
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for(count =1 ; count < 100;count++){
                    handler.post(updata);
                    try {
                        sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

А вот xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.x.threaddevelopmentpart2.MainActivity">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="376dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="169dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="331dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:text="More information"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="279dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="258dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="125dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Как исправить ошибку?

Comment: Судя по всему в 66 строке *MainActivity* вы пытаетесь использовать объект, который равен `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас `Handler handler;` объявлена, но не инициализирована. Засим она `null` и при обращении к ней вы и получаете ошибку. Приравняйте что-то подходящее этой переменной.